# Implicit arguments propagation

Tags: coq

Is it possible in Coq to implicitly propagate implicit arguments?

```
Class C := { n : nat }.

Section Sec.
  Context {c : C}.
  Definition f := fun x => x + n.
End Sec.

Fail Lemma f_inc : forall x, f x >= x.
```

For example here, after the end of section `Sec`, `c` is implicit argument of `f` but it is not automatically inserted as implicit argument of `f_inc`, which uses `f`.

I know this can be achieved by inserting `Context {c : C}.` before the lemma but it would make `c` an axiom and I still need the possibility to instantiate it later. I could also open a new section with context `c` but I don't want to put the whole project inside sections because of scoping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every argument must be explicitly *declared* somewhere. This declaration can either appear in a section (as you did for `f`), or in the header of a definition, lemma statement, etc. You have a few options here:

1. Bring `f_inc` inside the section where `f` is declared.
2. Put `f_inc` inside its own section, where `c : C` is also in the context.
3. Add `c : C` as an argument, implicitly or explicitly:

   ```
    Lemma f_inc {c : C} : forall x, f x >= x.
   ```

   You can also avoid having to name this argument explicitly, which is particularly useful when typeclasses are involved:

   ```
    Lemma f_inc `{C} : forall x, f x >= x.
   ```